# Is there a fix for the 'System.Object' error in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a Macbook Pro and I am emulating Win10 with VirtualBox to run Visual Code and it keeps giving me multiple errors like "predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported". It gives me the same errors with 'System.String' and 'System.Void', and when I run the application is giving me multiple build errors regarding this missing libraries. I already tried to check if all the components for Visual Code are correctly installed and I already have the .NET Core cross-platform development tools but I was not able to resolve the issue. Is there any workaround to have this working properly?

Comment: Doesn't Visual Studio Code work natively on mac?

Comment: @itsme86 it seems it doesn't have the same functionalities as the Win version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making some tests, I believe the problem was given by using VirtualBox as a vm software. I was not able to find a workaround and still use VB as main vm. I installed Parallels and I didn't find any error on my code. This is helpful in case you want to work with Windows Forms Applications in Visual Studio using a MacOS computer. This option is not available in the MacOS version of VS, so if the purpose is to use WFA, you can either use virtualization through Parallels Desktop  or installing Mono in your VS for Mac, as I read on other posts regarding this issue.